# Having issue with Cakephp Database Migrations

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to create a table using database migrations, here is my code

```
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('tags');
        $table->addColumn('title', 'string', ['default' => null,'limit' => 255,'null' => false,]);
        $table->addColumn('created', 'datetime', ['default' => null,'null' => false,]);
        $table->addColumn('modified', 'datetime', ['default' => null,'null' => false,]);
        $table->addUniqueKey('title');         // Giving error **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Phinx\Db\Table::addUniqueKey()**
        $table->create();
    }
```

I want to set `title` column unique, but when I try to do it then it gives the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Phinx\Db\Table::addUniqueKey()

Answer (score 0):

Add primary key refer http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html

```
    public function change() {
        $t = new Table('posts');
        $t->addColumn('id', 'integer')
          ->addColumn('author_id', 'integer')
          ->addColumn('title', 'string')
          ->addColumn('slug', 'string');

        // Add a primary key.
        $t->addConstraint('primary', [
            'type' => 'primary',
            'columns' => ['id']
        ]);

        // Add a unique key
        $t->addConstraint('slug_idx', [
            'columns' => ['slug'],
            'type' => 'unique',
        ]);

        // Add index
        $t->addIndex('slug_title', [
            'columns' => ['slug', 'title'],
            'type' => 'index'
        ]);

        // Add a foreign key
        $t->addConstraint('author_id_idx', [
            'columns' => ['author_id'],
            'type' => 'foreign',
            'references' => ['authors', 'id'],
            'update' => 'cascade',
            'delete' => 'cascade'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: now it gives this error: "key" is not a valid column option

Comment: but again i must say that i want to set unique key, not primary key. there is a huge difference between both

Comment: i really appreciate your hardwork, but i am sorry to say it still not works, better to test your code before posting

Comment: please review the documentation

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution

```
$table->addColumn('title', 'string', 
[
    'default' => null,
    'limit' => 255,
    'null' => false,
]);
$table->addIndex(['title'], ['unique' => true]); // < this is what you looking for
```

I am surprised CakePHP documentation doesn't mention it properly. After long searching, I found the solution in this [article](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#valid-column-options)